# @ComponentScan does not detect classes in module path

Tags: java, spring, java-11, java-module, jlink

I'm working on a JavaFX app with Java 11 and Spring. The app module is bundled with a custom JRE using `jlink`, which only allows named modules to be included in the bundle. Since Spring doesn't provide named modules but relies on automatic modules to achieve Java 9 Module System support, I use [moditect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) to add module descriptors (`module-info.java`) to the Spring JARs.

Compiling, `jlink`ing and executing the app works without any problems. However, Spring does not detect any of my app's classes annotated with `@Component`, despite my `AppConfig` class is annotated with `@ComponentScan`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
}
```

In `Main`, I create an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` based on `AppConfig` and print all registered beans as well as the resources available on class path:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainWindow) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Printing beans: " + applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames().length);
        for (String beanDefinitionName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanDefinitionName);
        }

        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resolver.getResources("classpath*:com/myapp/**/*.class")));
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        applicationContext.stop();
    }
}
```

If I run the app using IntelliJ, `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` finds all my classes on the class path (I guess because IntelliJ runs the app using the class path, not the module path). Consequently, all components are detected via component scan and the respective beans are created:

```
Printing beans: 8
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
appConfig
com.myapp.services.UserServiceImpl
com.myapp.services.BookingServiceImpl
[file [/Users/user/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/AppConfig.class], file [/Users/user/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/Main.class], file [/Users/user/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/services/UserService.class], file [/Users/user/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/services/UserServiceImpl.class], file [/Users/user/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/services/BookingService.class], file [/Users/user/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/services/BookingServiceImpl.class]]
```

But if I run the app via the `jlink`'ed bundle, i.e. on the custom JRE using the module path, Spring is unable to detect any of my classes:

```
Printing beans: 5
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
appConfig
[]
```

`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` does not find any classes (because everything is now located on the module path), and not a single bean is instantiated by the component scan.

If I import the component classes manually into `AppConfig`, the beans are created properly and also injected via `@Autowired`:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        com.myapp.service.UserServiceImpl.class,
        com.myapp.service.BookingServiceImpl.class
})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Why is Spring able to create the beans when using `@Import`, but does not detect them via `@ComponentScan`? How can I resolve my components via `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: Hello @IggyBlob, did you made any progress on this? I'm pretty much in the same hole...

Comment: @Mumrah81 I eventually managed to work around this issue by using this Gradle plugin: https://github.com/beryx/badass-runtime-plugin. It creates a custom runtime image for non-modular applications using the following steps:

1) Create a classic (pre-Java-9-style) distribution (i.e. a fat JAR that also contains the non-modular Spring dependencies) 
2) Use jlink to create a custom JRE containing only the modules required by the application
3) Merge the pre-Java-9-style distribution into the custom JRE and adjust the start scripts with appropriate JVM settings flags such as --module-path.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution than the one provided by @IggyBlob in the question's comments is to patch `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` to search resources into the module path at least until a fully module compliant Spring version is released.

One possible implementation:

```
public class PathMatchingResourcePatternResolverJigsaw extends PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver {

    public PathMatchingResourcePatternResolverJigsaw() {
    }

    public PathMatchingResourcePatternResolverJigsaw(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        super(resourceLoader);
    }

    public PathMatchingResourcePatternResolverJigsaw(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(classLoader);
    }

    public List<Resource> getResourcesFromModules(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
        String pattern = locationPattern.substring(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX.length());
        List<Resource> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ModuleLayer.boot().configuration().modules().stream()
         .map(ResolvedModule::reference)
         .forEach(mref -> {
             try (ModuleReader reader = mref.open()) {
                 list.addAll(reader.list()
                    .filter(p -> getPathMatcher().match(pattern, p))
                    .map(p -> {
                        try {
                            return convertClassLoaderURL(reader.find(p).get().toURL());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                 throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
            }
         });
        return list;
    }
    @Override
    public Resource[] getResources(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
        boolean addModSearch = true;

        Resource[] result = super.getResources(locationPattern);
        if (addModSearch && locationPattern.startsWith(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX)) {
            List<Resource> list = getResourcesFromModules(locationPattern);
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(result));
            result = list.toArray(new Resource[0]);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And initialize your spring appllication context with:

```
private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> initializer = new ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext>() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext) {
                genericApplicationContext.setResourceLoader(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolverJigsaw());
            }
        };

        this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(MyApplication.class)
                .initializers(initializer)
                .build().run(new String[0]);
    }
```

This is only an ugly workaround, so use it with caution